# How to emulate keyboard event in application

Tags: android

I need to use button in my activity instead android keyboard. 
I finde example (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html):

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

    ic.deleteSurroundingText(4, 0);

    ic.commitText("Hello", 1);

    ic.commitText("!", 1);
```

But I can't understand how use it in my application. Where should I create class that extends InputMethodService, and what this class must have.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must create a class that extends EditText. then you can ovveride onCreateInputConnection method.